# How to save a `DateTime` instance of Dart to sqlite `timestamp` field?

Tags: sqlite, datetime, timestamp, dart

I'm using [dart-sqlite](https://github.com/sam-mccall/dart-sqlite) to operate sqlite in Dart.

Sqlite has a `timestamp` field, and Dart has a type of `DateTime`. But when I insert an `DateTime` instance to sqlite, it will throw an error of:

```
Uncaught Error: SqliteException: Invalid parameter type
Stack Trace:
#0      _bind (package:dart-sqlite/sqlite.dart:246:1)
#1      Statement.execute (package:dart-sqlite/sqlite.dart:142:33)
#2      Database.execute (package:dart-sqlite/sqlite.dart:78:31)
#3      Database.execute (package:dart-sqlite/sqlite.dart:79:7)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SQLite only has direct support for a few datatypes. Quoting from their official documentation:](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

> **NULL.** The value is a NULL value.
>
> **INTEGER.** The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.
>
> **REAL.** The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.
>
> **TEXT.** The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).
>
> **BLOB.** The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

You'll note there is no direct means of storing a date or time. However, you could insert an integer representation of the value, perhaps by using [DateTime's `millisecondsSinceEpoch` and `fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch` methods](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/DateTime.html). You can also insert a string, if that's easier for you to work with.

If you really must insert binary data, you can use a BLOB, but that's usually not a good idea for anything that has semantic meaning in your program.

Comment: You are right. It's a good idea to use `millisecondsSinceEpoch` to store a number